# Is this an attempted cross-site attack?

Tags: attacks, webserver

I have found various 404 errors in my web server log that look like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/go.php?http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ffdkafkjasd
http://mywebsite.com/go?http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ffdkafkjasd
http://mywebsite.com/raw.php?http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ffdkafkjasd
```

None of these URLs have ever existed (my website is not even PHP-based). It looks like someone is attempting to guess a URL for a page on my website which causes a browser redirect to pastebin.com.

What is this person trying to do? Is it some sort of attempted hack?

Comment: Apart from an awkward automated blind injection attack, I can not see something else.

Comment: Is this an attempted cross-site attack? NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script or bot is probably probing for an [Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet) vulnerability.

The reason I say this over [SSRF](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/server-side-request-forgery-vulnerability/) is because the target domain is `pastbin.com`, and not a domain under control of the attacker. The attacker will have no way of knowing if a SSRF attack worked without validating that the server-side request was made, therefore this is unlikely.

However, with Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards the attacker just needs to look for a redirect HTTP response such as 301 Permanent. If successful, they could then use your site in a phishing style attack using an obfuscated redirect domain (say percent encoded) in the hope their victim follows the link to your (trusted) domain.